# How to move up lines in a .txt file with BufferedReader?

Tags: java, io

Making an "assembler" program for a CS course I am enrolled in. It has functions like ADD, SET, INC (increment), and JIG. Now, we are inputing a .txt file with the following layout (as example):

Keep note: A and B are just integer's that store the value throughout the program, and print out the value once it reaches the end of the text file.

```
INC A    (increments A by 1)
SET B 5   (set's B's value to 5)
INC B
ADD A 3  (add's 3 to A's current value)
JIG B -4 (move's backward 4 lines, so back to INC A)
```

So what I am confused how to do is move my BufferedReader back 4 lines? Is there a method in BufferedReader that lets you move it to a certain index/position? Otherwise, how else can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is store the lines in an array or List.

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("myfile.txt"));
```

This will allow you to progress to any line at random.

To get any line you can use `lines.get(n)` For example you can do

```
int pointer = 0;
for(boolean running = true; running && pointer < lines.size(); ) {
   String line = lines.get(pointer);
   String[] parts = line.split(" +");
   switch(part[0]) {
      case "JMP":
          pointer += Integer.parseInt(parts[1]); // jump back or forth.
          continue;
      case "HALT":
          running = false;
          break;
      // other instructions
   }
   pointer++;
}
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels it needs to return a list. but you are right.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, Peter! However, is it possible to pass in a File instead of a String ("myfile.txt")? Because the way my program is written I use :                                                                              FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(file);
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));

Comment: You can get `Paths.get(file.toString())`

Comment: Thanks that compiled. Now how do I go about implementing this technique? How can I use it to retrieve certain lines? thanks.

Comment: @bobafro You look up the list using your code pointer, I have added an example.

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate it

Comment: @bobafro to make it really efficient you could convert the assembly to Java code and compile it or byte code.